# How to validate expiry date in php on local server (like xampp) project with no internet connection

Tags: php, codeigniter

It works fine when system has correct date time.But when a user changed system date time by control panel(window system) then it bypass the security.I use this condition to validate.

```
if( (strtotime($this->system_date) <= strtotime($license_arr[4])) ){
     die('***********Licence Valid *****************');
}
else{
     die('***********Licence In-Valid *****************');
}
```

on `[4]` key of `$license_arr` expiry date used.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch current datetime from your database also. 
So user "system date" must be greater than "current datetime"
Check if your `user "system date"` between  `database fetched datetime` &   `$license_arr expiry` then it is valid

Comment: Hi Dipanwita ,thanks for your answer.I have checked it with mysql now() function it is giving me wrong date.It is giving same date as system date set.

Answer (score 0):

It takes server date and time, restricts physical access to your server.